# How to apply custom single.php to specific posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to have different single.php for specific posts. I would like to apply custom `single.php` to posts with numbers I want. How can I do that?

Wordpress admin shows number 280 for post I would like to use custom `single.php`

*wiseoid.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=280&action=edit*

Kindly let me know what is the easiest solution, do I have to make another code in functions.php? The reason I want to use custom single.php is because Google Adsense doesn't allow words like pornography even if the article has educational purpose. I need to replace 2 adsense units with other ads for specific posts.

Comment: The article has single.php applied to category and author but not to number of  post.

Comment: but you can do it - `single-post-{slug}.php `

Comment: @Stender that is for post type single page.

Comment: @Tristup no? `single-{post-type}-{slug}.php` – (Since 4.4) First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post. For example, if post type is product and the post slug is dmc-12, WordPress would look for single-product-dmc-12.php.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post

Comment: This is just basic templating, the highest point in the single hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you. This is easy.

Comment: @Stender, you are correct that is written here, have tested whether is working or not?

Comment: @virmodrosti, great it helps you. Thanks for selecting my answer, please upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily with **template_include** filter, please find the code below. It will add a custom template from **theme folder-> single post layout**. I have done actually with a custom plugin created myself named **Ze Single Post Layout.**

```
add_filter('template_include', 'ze_single_post_templates');
function  ze_single_post_templates( $template ) {
    $post_types = array('post');
    $post_id=get_the_ID();

    if (is_singular($post_types)) {        
        if($post_id==280)
        {
            $template = get_template_directory().'single-post-layouts/custom-layout1.php';          
        }  
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: How can you add another post id to this script?

Comment: Cant get your question actually.

Comment: this script is made for post 280, what if I want post 280 and 429 for example?

Comment: I tried to simply put another number after 280 but it doesn't work. Wordpress requires some array or what?

Comment: use if($post_id==280 || $post_id==281 )